# Why is this variadic template an error?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Just wondering why is this invalid:

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t... Is>
void foo(Is&&... args) {
    std::cout << "foo called with " << sizeof...(Is) << "params\n"; 
}

int main() {
    foo(1, 2, 3, 4); 
}
```

It seems a perfectly reasonable example, yet it [**fails**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc011ce5cd3063f9) on any compiler I can get my hands on.

If I substitute `size_t` for `class` the example works as expected. I've also tried using the new `auto` template parameter but no online compiler accepts this so I don't know if this an invalid use case or a conformance issue.

Comment: `Is` is not a type.  It is a value of `size_t`.

Comment: You would never write `void foo(1 a, 2 b, 3 c, ...)`, so why would you write `void foo(Is... )`? ;)

Comment: @BaummitAugen that dupe target dose not look right

Comment: @NathanOliver Why? You cannot deduce non-type template arguments, variadic or not makes no difference.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The problem is not deduction here, the problem is that OP is trying to use a non-type template arguments to specify the type of arguments... I don't know how you call that, but this has nothing to do with non-type template argument deduction.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Because the OP isn't even trying to deuce the values.  He is confused on the difference between a type and non type template.  We never even get to deduction since `void foo(Is&&... args)` is a flat out compiler error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not valid C++, that's why.

If you instantiate that function template with the template arguments `1, 2, 3, 4` then after substituting the arguments into the template you get the signature:

```
void foo(1&&, 2&&, 3&&, 4&&);
```

That's clearly not a valid function.

If you want to write a function template that accepts any number of arguments but only if they are of the right type, you can do that like this in C++17:

```
template<typename T>
  using is_size_t = std::is_same<T, std::size_t>;

template<typename... T>
  std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction<is_size_t<T>...>::value>>
  foo(T&&... args);
```

Or alternatively (also using C++17):

```
template<typename... T>
  std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, T> && ...)>
  foo(T&&... args);
```

For C++14 you need to implement `std::conjunction` yourself, e.g. using the `and_` template from [p0032r1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0013r1.html#impl)

Comment: I don't think C++14 has fold expressions?

Comment: @Barry, oops, I forgot how primitive C++14 is ;)

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's not primitive, it's otherwise complete.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with another language lately and totally pulled a Monika there. Just to complement Jonathan's answer, (thanks for the explanation and the comments) this is how to ensure all parameters are of `size_t` type (what I was actually trying to do) [**using concepts**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f79200d022351a):

```
template <class... Is>
    requires (std::is_same<Is, int>::value && ...)
void foo(Is&&... args) { /*...*/ }
```

Or even (ma fav) by **defining a dedicated concept**

```
template <class T> concept bool Integer = std::is_same<T, int>::value; 

template <Integer... Is> void foo(Is&&... args) { /*...*/ }
//        ^^^^^^^awesome
```

[**Live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3061d6c13715dfb7)

Comment: Concepts are not part of the C++ language.

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm not saying they are, am I? One of the reasons for delaying their addition was so that the C++ community would experiment, test and elaborate on them